# What is wrong with this SQL command for Apache Open Office Base?

Tags: sql, syntax, openoffice-base

I am an online student and have just started to learn SQL. I am doing an exercise where I have to create a new database with the following command in Apache Open Office 4.1.3.

```
CREATE TABLE "tbl_customers" ("customer_id" INTEGER IDENTITY, "first_name" VARCHAR(50), "last_name" VARCHAR(50), "phone" VARCHAR(25), "email" VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY ( "customer_id"));
```

`syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting ')' or ','`

This is a command that an instructor uses on her computer on the other side of the world, in the same version of Open Office, and it executes for her. I have uninstalled, restarted the computer and reinstalled the program, checked the commas and apostrophes, but whatever I try, it keeps giving me the above error.

Comment: This command runs fine in MS SQL Server! You can try taking out all of the double quotes as they aren't necessary in this example. Your syntax might be a little different depending on the type of database server you are using, check out this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: Do you have code before or after this? That might be where your issue is...

Comment: Hi Lucky. Thank you. No, I don't have code before or after this. This is literally the first command I need to run. I actually tried removing the double quotes (without success) but as far as I know Open Office Base needs them.

Comment: Try removing IDENTITY from there

Comment: The error message changed to:
1: The query can not be executed. It is too complex.

Comment: If that works your server wants a seed and increment, like IDENTITY(1,1). See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. I get the original error message if I add the increment.

Comment: Sorry man, I'm out of ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.  Did you run the command by going to *Tools -> SQL*?  Here are step by step instructions.

1. Create a new Base file.  For example from Writer, go to *File -> New -> Database*.
2. *Create a new database* should be marked by default.  This will use the HSQLDB 1.8 engine in an embedded setup  (not good for real work, but okay for testing.)
3. Press Next, then mark *No, do not register the database.*  Or mark *Yes* if using it from Calc.  Be sure that *Open the database for editing* is marked, then press Finish.
4. Save as "New Database.odb" or give it a different name.
5. Go to *Tools -> SQL* and paste the command.  Then press Execute.
   [image: execute]
6. Close and then go to *View -> Refresh Tables* to show the "tbl_customers" table.

Comment: I followed the above but it still gives the same error message. I have been using the the Tools --> SQL command all along.

Comment: Screenshot:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1R4nPBfoahaNHA5WWxGa19rV1k

Comment: Well, that's strange.  I tested this with the English-US 32-bit AOO installer, running on Windows 10 (64-bit system, 64-bit processor).  What operating system and language did you [download](https://www.openoffice.org/download/)?  I recommend a 32-bit installer.  One more suggestion: Try LibreOffice; it's newer and better in many ways.

Comment: I downloaded Windows 32 bit  English and running it on a 64 bit Windows 7. I'll give libre office a try.

Comment: Thank you @Jim K, Libre Office runs the command just fine. Something with my Apache OpenOffice was really not working.